# Tf-Idf calculation in python

Tags: python, list, tf-idf

I'm new to python, I was looking to write a function that calculates the term frequency-inverse document frequency given two parameters.

Parameters:
        docs........list of lists, where each sublist contains the tokens for one document.
        doc_freqs...dict from term to document frequency (In how many documents a specific term ).

Desired Output:

```
index = create_tfidf_index([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a']], {'a': 2., 'b': 1., 'c': 1.})
index['a']
[[0, 0.0], [1, 0.0]]
index['b']  
[[0, 0.301...]]
```

My code to find doc_freq(second parameter in tfidf function)

```
def count_doc_frequencies(docs):
    tmp = []
    lst = {}
    for item in docs: tmp += set(item)
    for key in tmp: lst[key] = lst.get(key, 0) + 1
    return lst

res = Index().count_doc_frequencies([['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']])
res['a']
3
```

Now can anyone help me how to calculate tf-idf using these two parameters which i've described above and produce the output as i've shown..

Please help guys!!!

Comment: Did you consider using scikit learn for this? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#tokenizing-text-with-scikit-learn) unless you have to write the function yourself for the exam.

Here is a decent [tutorial](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html).

Official documentation on this is pretty good too. It demonstrates [tokenization](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#tokenizing-text-with-scikit-learn) and actual [tf-idf calculation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#from-occurrences-to-frequencies).

Hope this helps some.